# How to generate a large number of constraints for all indices ($\forall i$)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

Is it possible to generate a set of constraints in the form "$\forall$".
For example:

\begin{align}
\min\  & f\left(\sum x_i\right)\\
s.t.\ & \\
& x_i\geq 17 && \forall i=1,...,n.
\end{align}
What would be the best way to create this set of constraints in the code? Possibly when using `FindMin` or `NMinimize`.

Comment: `n=5; vars=Array[x,n]; NMinimize[{f[Total[vars]], And @@ (# >= 17 & /@ vars)}, vars]`

Comment: [`ForAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll.html) is for different things in Mathematica's Logic & Boolean Algebra features when used with `Resolve`,`Reduce`, and `FindInstance` and not relevant to numerical minimization here.

Comment: `NMinimize[Join[{f[Total[vars]]}, Thread[vars >= 17]], vars]` should also do... When the first argument of `NMinimize` is a list, the first entry is interpreted as objective function and the remaining ones are interpreted as constraints.